# Exception Will not Print Message

Tags: java, exception

InputMisMatch Exception

In Java. I have user to input two numbers and if they aren't the same then a Input Mismatch Exception will print out a message. However it's not printing the message. what I'm doing wrong.

```
package Day4;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {
    int num1 = 0;
    int num2 = 0;



    void add(){

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter two numbers:");
        int num1 = sc.nextInt();
        int num2 = sc.nextInt();



        try {
            try{

                System.out.println(num1 + num2);

            }
            catch(InputMismatchException e)
                {
                num1 = sc.nextInt();
                num2 = sc.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Invalid Character");
             }


           }
            catch (ArithmeticException ae)
             {
                System.out.println("Invalid Number Try again");

               } 
        }






       public static void main(String[] args) {

        Calculator c = new Calculator();
        c.add();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     }

}
```

Comment: Which part of your code should be throwing an exception if the two inputs aren't the same?

Comment: You need to a) determine if there is a mismatch b) if so, throw the exception yourself - there is nothing in your code that will throw an `InputMismatchException`

Comment: Your code formation is messy. To your question: I would recommend some tutorial(s) about exceptions, e.g. [this one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/).

Comment: I'm new to Java be nice ! .. The user input would be two numbers say 1, 3 then the out put would be 4. If the input is 1 and n then it would be input mismatch and should print out Invalid character.

Comment: _it should_ Which part of your code do you think does that at the moment?

Comment: the second try statement ? @SotiriosDelimanolis

Comment: A try statement doesn't throw exceptions. It prepares to handle them. If you want an exception thrown, you need to throw it yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I would recommend you to read about how try and catch blocks work, and multicatch.

So according to you code I'm assuming you want to prevent the user from inputtin non-integer numbers

Now the answer:

The line of your code that is throwing the Exception is:

```
int num1 = sc.nextInt();
int num2 = sc.nextInt();
```

Not:

```
System.out.println( num1 + num2 );
```

So the right way to do i would be:

```
System.out.println( "enter two numbers:" );

try {
    int num1 = sc.nextInt();
    int num2 = sc.nextInt();

   System.out.println( num1+num2 );

}
catch(InputMismatchException e){
    System.out.println("Invalid Character");
}
```

The AritmethicException wouldn't be thrown since both are already *int*

Comment: Thank you!!! :) I understand completely. I've cleaned my code up as well. @J.Pichardo I wasn't sure if I could use catch more than once in a single method.

Comment: If it worked as answer, I would appreciate if you marked it as an answer.
Welcome to Java.

Comment: Yes it did. My apologies I'm new to stack as well. *Doing it now :) @J. Pichardo

Comment: Thanks @CassandraB